# Telerik Grid - Date Column - Filtering on past date not working

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have below code,

```
   @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Results)
            .Name("ResultsGrid")
            .NoRecordsTemplate("No records found.")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {

                columns.Bound(s => s.Id).Title("User Id").Template(
                        model => @Html.ActionLink(model.Id.ToString(), "Action1", "Controller1", new { UserId = model.Id}, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "xyz" } })
                ).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Address).Title("Address").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Address" });
                columns.Bound(s => s.City).Title("City").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "City" }).Width(140);
                columns.Bound(s => s.State).Title("State").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "State" }).Width(60);
                columns.Bound(s => s.Zip).Title("Zip").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Zip" }).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(s => s.FromDate).Title("From Date").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "From Date" }).Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}").Width(160);
                columns.Bound(s => s.ToDate).Title("To Date").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "To Date" }).Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}").Width(180);
            })
            .ClientEvents(e => e.OnLoad("alignHeight")) 
            .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
            {
                dataBinding.Server().Select("SameAction", "SameController");
            })
            .Scrollable(sc => sc.Enabled(true))
            .Sortable(so => so.Enabled(true))
            .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10).Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndDropDown).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
            .Filterable(f => f.Enabled(true))
            .Groupable(g => g.Enabled(false))
            .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
        )
```

Filtering on Date columns works fine for current and future date but when i try to filter using past dates. Grid is showing "No records found." I have records with past dates, i was expecting the grid to display matches the filter. I am trying to filter by applying "is equals to" operator.

Is there any additional code i have to implement to handle past dates for Date column?

Comment: Below is the request passed to controller, 

(http://localhost/SameController/SameAction?
ResultsGrid-page=1
&ResultsGrid-orderBy=~
&ResultsGrid-filter=FromDate~eq~datetime'2010-04-22T00-00-00' - Past Date
&ResultsGrid-size=10)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my problem. Before binding convert DateTime to Date.